# How to save the state of the checkbox to core data in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, checkbox

**I'm not a good English speaker. Please forgive me for my awkward English.

I'm working on a to do list project using checkbox. I cannot find a way to save the state of the checkbox to core data

This is a part of the code I use right now. `Tasks`is the Entity (class definition) and it has `isMarked` as a Boolean Attribute.
(I cut a lot to make it simple so if you find something strange in the code please write a comment)

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

var toDolist: [Tasks] = []

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(toDoTable)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var toDoTable: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return toDolist.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomTableViewCell
        cell.box.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "uncheckedbox"), for: .normal)

        let task = toDolist[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func getData(){
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        do{
            toDolist = try context.fetch(Tasks.fetchRequest())
        }catch{
            print("fetching failed")
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        getData()
        toDoTable.reloadData()
    }

}


class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var box: CheckBox!
    @IBOutlet weak var taskLbl: UILabel!
}

class CheckBox{
    var isChecked: Bool = false{
        didSet{
            if isChecked == true{
                self.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "checkedbox"), for: .normal)
            }else{
                self.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "uncheckedbox"), for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib(){
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.isChecked = false
    }

    func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton){
        if sender == self{
            if isChecked == true{
                isChecked = false
            }else{
                isChecked = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this by adding some code to it? Or do I have to change all the code above?

Comment: You have to connect (by references) the data model – the `Task` instances – to the state and the action of the button. The most convenient way is to pass a `Task` instance in `cellForRow` to the custom table view cell. Due to reference semantics any changes will persist and you only need to save the managed object context. Actually subclassing `UIButton` is overkill.

Comment: @vadian I deleted the 'UIButton' subclassing but how can I pass a 'Tasks' instance in 'cellForRow'(did you mean 'cellForRowAt' ? ) to the custom tableview cell? Did you mean I have to chose Manual/None instead of Class Definition? Sorry but I'm just a beginner in programming and English....

Comment: • Add a property `var task : Tasks!` in the cell and add a line `cell.task = task` in `cellForRowAt`. Now you handed over the data source item to the cell. • Add the `didSet` observer to `task` to set `isChecked`  to the current value. • Add an `IBAction` in the cell to receive the touch and connect it in Interface Builder. • In the action toggle `isChecked`, update the image and the property in `task`. • Save the context.

Comment: " Add an 'IBAction' in the cell" means add it in the func 'cellForRowAt'?  I couldn't do that, and i tried to addTarget the box in the func cellForRowAt but also I couldn't make it work well. or should I add a new transparent action button on the cell to do so? Sorry for these consecutive rudimentary questions.

Comment: No, *in the cell* means in the `CustomTableViewCell` class (where the button belongs to).

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution:

- Remove the subclass of `UIButton` and revert the class of the button to `UIButton`.
- In Interface Builder assign the images `checkedbox` and `uncheckedbox` to the button for states `selected` and `default`. The images are displayed automatically depending on the `isSelected` property of the button. That avoids completely to update the images in code.
- The class `CustomTableViewCell` got the property `task` and the `IBAction` which must be connected to `Touch Up Inside` of the button. The property `isSelected` of the `task` must be changed to the name of the attribute of the `NSManagedObject`

  ```
  class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

      @IBOutlet weak var box: UIButton!
      @IBOutlet weak var taskLbl: UILabel!

      var task : Tasks! {
          didSet {
              box.isSelected = task.isSelected
              taskLbl.text = // update the label
          }
      }

      @IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton)
      {
          let selected = !sender.isSelected
          sender.isSelected = selected
          task.isSelected = selected
          // save the context if needed
      }

  }
  ```
- In `cellForRowAt` just add the line to assign the `task`

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomTableViewCell
      let task = toDolist[indexPath.row]
      cell.task = task
      return cell
  }
  ```

Comment: Actually the Entity `Tasks` has `isMarked` as its Attributes but except that, it worked perfectly ! Thank you so much.(Sorry but I can't up vote this because I seem to lack of enough reputation or something like that.. )