# Table view check box not accepting action for index 0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view, in which I have the items with check boxes. Users can select any items (multiselection also) and they can press the Proceed button to pay.

I was using a button as a check box. So if the user presses the button, or they select a table row, both cases are handled the function.

So now, my proceed buton starts as disabled. Whenever the user presses any items using the `didSelectRowAt` method or check box button action, only then the Proceed button will be enabled.

But now, whenever I press the first item or the first check box button, my proceed button is not getting enabled. If I press the second item or the second check box, it works. I don't know why.

Here is my code of `didSelectRowAt` and my check box button action code:

#Updated:

```
 var selectedIndexPathArray = Array<NSIndexPath>()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemcell", for: indexPath) as! itemTableViewCell


        cell.checkboxBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        if selectedIndexPathArray.contains(indexPath as NSIndexPath) {
            cell.checkboxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "enabled"), for: .normal)
            proceedbutton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true


        } else {
            cell.checkboxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "disabled"), for: .normal)
            proceedbutton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        }
        return cell
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if selectedIndexPathArray.contains(indexPath as NSIndexPath) {

             let index = selectedIndexPathArray.index(of: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
            selectedIndexPathArray.remove(at: index!)
        } else {
            selectedIndexPathArray.append(indexPath as NSIndexPath)
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should include the `selected` state in the model rather than using an extra array and don't use `NSIndexPath` in Swift 3+

Comment: @vadian  i am not sure , how can i update my solution Can u please update that

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397812/how-to-make-checkmark-to-be-selected-depending-on-the-array-in-swift-3/46398755#46398755 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44699371/how-to-save-the-state-of-the-checkbox-to-core-data-in-swift/44704524#44704524 for examples how to include the selection information in the model

Comment: @david, where is the code for the checkBox handler? And you mean like when you select the first checkBox the proceedButton shall be enabled?

Comment: Checkbox handle code is not there, please see my update post. And now i may have more than 5 data with check box, but if i select my second cell item or 3rd then my proceed button is enable , but if i select my first cell data only.My proceed button is not enabling

Answer (score 0):

Yes because first time if you click on button then `proceedbutton` will be called and at that time `selectedIndexPathArray` will have no any value means nil.

So first time your **else** part will be executed.

```
.
.
.
 else {    
           selectedIndexPathArray.append(indexPath! as NSIndexPath)
           cell?.checkboxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "disabled"), for: .normal)
           proceedbutton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

      }
```

And when you press agin then your **if** condition will be true so it will be **enable**

Comment: ia m not getting ur solution..can u please updated fully code.. wr i need to put this else part

Comment: Now wha should i need to do with that , to work as i expect ??

Comment: Can u post full solution , i replease the changes.Then also i am not getting

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your if-else condition on your proceed() function.

```
    if selectedIndexPathArray.contains(indexPath! as NSIndexPath) {
        electedIndexPathArray.remove(at: index!)
        cell?.checkboxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "disabled"), for: .normal)
        proceedbutton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
    else {

        selectedIndexPathArray.append(at: index!)
        cell?.checkboxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "enabled"), for: .normal)
        proceedbutton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove selector for button in cell and default set userInteraction for button is false.No need to set it everytime. Perform everything on didSelectRow.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: itemscell, for: indexPath) as! itemsTableViewCell

     cell?.checkboxBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        if selectedIndexArray.contains(indexPath.row) {
            cell.checkboxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "enabled"), for: .normal)
            proceedbutton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        } else {
            cell.checkboxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "disabled"), for: .normal)
            proceedbutton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if selectedIndexArray.contains(indexPath.row) {
            let index = selectedIndexPathArray.index(of: indexPath.row)
            selectedIndexArray.remove(at: index!)
        } else {
            selectedIndexArray.append(indexPath.row)
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: then how can i disable and enable the proceedbutton . This proceed button is like cell checkbox button action only

Comment: still that issue is there. Any other solution please

Comment: please see my updated post. After update ur solution also i am getting same issue

Comment: I dont knwo wr i am doing wrong. I am getting same issue now also. ` var selectedIndexPathArray = Array<NSIndexPath>()`

Comment: var selectedIndexPathArray = [Int]()
I have used indexPath.row so it is array of Integers.

Comment: still i am getting same issue and crash on here `selectedIndexPathArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)`  console :`stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.`

Comment: Any other possiblities please??

Comment: see i have updated that crash lines
let index = selectedIndexPathArray.index(of: indexPath.row)
                selectedIndexArray.remove(at: index!)

Comment: that crsh i fixed, but still if select first cell, then my proceed button is not enable, if i select second only my proceed button is enable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156324/discussion-between-nishant-bhindi-and-david).