# How to remove particular data from table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have list of product items to display in my table view. At the same time i have i have some other api call, Where i will pass my prodcut item name to check. If that product item is available then that particular data or item cell alone will be highlighted and it will be disabled.

Now what i need is, when i do api call, and after that if that particular data or product name is available in that api, instead of highlight and disable... I should not show that particular data in my table view.

How to do that:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! AllConnectionsTableViewCell

 if let contact = filtered?[indexPath.row]{
                cell.emailOutlet.text = AccountDataCache.sharedInstance.displayMaskAccnt(items: product.name)
                cell.nameOutlet.text = product.name
    if let _ = self.checkapicall(items: product.name){

                      // here if my product name is availble in api, then only the backgroudnd and it will be disabled



if let product = filtered?[indexPath.row]{

                cell.namelabel.text = product.name
 if let _ = self.checkapicall(items: product.vpa){



                    cell.cellOuterView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

                }else{
                    cell.cellOuterView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

                }

}


}
```

Instead of chnaging BG, Disable..i should not show that data in that tableview cell.How to do that.?

Thanks

Comment: Show you model that you´re using to populate the your tableView.

Comment: @RashwanL i have updated. Like how i am populating data to my table view

Comment: @RashwanL  this `var filtered: [allitems]?` in that `allitems` contains the product name tahst all like `var name = ""` and it was map like` func mapping(map: Map) {
        vpaname<- map["name"] }`

Comment: Do you want to remove the entire cell and go on to the next row or do you want to show the cell but not any text on it?

Comment: my table view will look like this with data `name1, name2,name3, name4` if my `name2` is available in my api call. Then my table view should be like this `name1,name3,name4`

Comment: @RashwanL  Is it clear?. Shall i exaplin once o no need ???

Comment: Checkout my answer, it will give you a hint of how to get started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you described, if your data looks like this:

```
name1, name2,name3, name4
```

Then you want to show four rows in your `tableView`.

If `name2` is available in your API call then you want to show this:

```
name1, name3, name4
```

So what you need to do is to get all the names before you start updating the `tableView`. This is because you need to set how many rows you want to display in your `tableView`.

You could do something like this (I´m not sure how you fetch your data today, but this is an example to get you started):

```
// check add edit to your product
var products = [Product(name: "name1", vpa: "1"), Product(name: "name2", vpa: "2"), Product(name: "name3", vpa: "3"), Product(name: "name4", vpa: "4")]

// set the produts count
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return products.count
}

// just set the name here, don´t make any checks
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StartPageCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.namelabel.text = product.name
    return cell
}

// check the names here and then reload the tableView
func checkNames() {
    for product in products {
        if self.checkapicall(items: product.vpa){ {
             if let index = products.index(where: { $0.vpa == vpa }) {
            products.remove(at: index)
        }
        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: i am getting this error ` Type 'allitems' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'`  on tis line`for product in products {`

Comment: @david, add your `product` model to your answer. Or even better upload your project to Dropbox or Google Drive and post the link here and I´ll take a look at your project.

Comment: I will try to upload my project. can u please have a look on this.Still this also i was not able to solve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46641892/table-view-check-box-not-accepting-action-for-index-0

Comment: this var filtered: [allitems]? in that allitems contains the product name tahst all like var name = "" and it was map like` func mapping(map: Map) { vpaname<- map["name"] }

Comment: Any solution please

Comment: Zip your project and upload it to Dropbox/Google drive and I´ll have a look at it.

Comment: i was not able to upload..i dont have acces...is that not clear ??

Comment: I have update my post with clear cell row for index method of table view...Please help me

Comment: @david, join [this](https://appear.in/stackoverflow) video conference and share your screen and I´ll see how I can help you. With the given information I´m not sure how to help you. I´m waiting in there.

Comment: sure, thank...Do u have skype or shall we continue on that link ??

Comment: Go to that link, I´m in there.

Comment: @david, did you manage to solve this? If my answer was useful, click the upvote button to the left of it. If it answered your question, click the checkmark to accept it. That way others know that you"ve been (sufficiently) helped.

Comment: yeah, can u please help me on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46641892/table-view-check-box-not-accepting-action-for-index-0

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't make such checks in `cellForRow`, make it in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`

- Add a property `var isAvailable = false` to your product model
- In `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` check the availability of the products and set `isAvailable` accordingly.
- Create the data source array `var filtered = [Product]()` (assuming `Product` is the data model) and filter the items `filtered = allItems.filter { $0.isAvailable }`
- Reload the table